# Multiple Select Join query with corresponding column on one table to others

Tags: mysql

Lets say that I have something table like this:

```
<b>Name</b>
+---------+--------+
| name_id | name   |
+---------+--------+
| 5       | Betti  |
| 6       | Derry  |
| 7       | Alfred |
| 8       | Elsie  |
| 9       | Cinta  |
+---------+--------+

<b>Goods</b>
+----------+-----------+
| goods_id | goods     |
+----------+-----------+
| 1        | Computer  |
| 2        | AC        |
| 3        | Microwave |
| 4        | TV        |
+----------+-----------+

<b>Transaction</b>
+-------+---------+----------+
| ai_id | name_id | goods_id |
+-------+---------+----------+
| 1     | 7       | 2        |
| 2     | 5       | 4        |
| 3     | 9       | 3        |
+-------+---------+----------+
```

I want to replace ***name_id*** column on **Transaction** table with ***name*** column on **Name** table with corresponding name_id column and so for goods_id to produce something similar to this table:

```
<b>Transaction</b>
+-------+--------+-----------+
| ai_id | name   | goods     |
+-------+--------+-----------+
| 1     | Alfred | AC        |
| 2     | Betti  | TV        |
| 3     | Cinta  | Microwave |
+-------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: When you say replace, do you mean actually modifying your table or just display that information with a select query?

Comment: I want to just display the information based on corresponding ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to just display the information rather than actually "replacing" your tables with new ones, then you could use a `SELECT` query with a simple `INNER JOIN`. This way you can display columns from multiple tables.

```
SELECT T.ai_id, N.Name, G.goods
FROM Transaction T
    INNER JOIN Name N ON N.name_id = T.name_id
    INNER JOIN Goods G ON G.goods_id = T.goods_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

***try this:***

```
SELECT C.ai_id,A.name,B.goods
FROM Transaction C 
INNER JOIN Name A 
ON A.name_id=C.name_id
INNER JOIN Goods B 
ON B.goods_id=C.goods_id;
```

***http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c5f3/8***

Answer (score 0):

Try with inner join

```
SELECT T.ai_id,N.name,G.goods 
FROM Transaction as T
INNER JOIN Goods as G ON T.goods_id = G.goods_id
INNER JOIN Name as N ON N.name_id = T.name_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
select tb3.ai_id,tb2.name,tb1.goods from  Goods tb1,Name tb2,Transaction tb3 where tb3.name_id=tb2.name_id and tb3.goods_id=tb1.goods_id order by tb3.ai_id
```